# How to install .tar.bz2

Tags: installation, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I have downloaded wine using the download location at the site. The download is a file.tar.bz2. I have extracted it and it gives me a lot of files but nothing that seems to be executable. How can I install it without using the software center?

Comment: I recommend using `sudo apt-get install wine`

Answer (score 1):

Usually:

```
tar -xf file.tar.bz2
cd dir_name
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

*dir_name* is the same as file name but without file extension.

You would probobly need build-essential package before compiling.

You can install it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

---

Like iSeth said it's better and simpler to install Wine from repo by just typing:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile it. It usually has a readme or an install text file which explains the steps to successfully install it.